# Shortcut bash script

Tags: php, bash

I am writing a php script in Linux. Some of my scripts need lots of parameters. For example:

```
myscript --param1=val --param2=val filename param3
```

So the "myscript" is a linux script and the filename is a custom file I need to call. param3 is used in filename. For example

```
php process.php top 3
```

Now sometimes I need to use different `php.ini` or ini setting so I use:

```
php -d <phpoption>=1 process.php top 3
```

or

```
php -d xdebug.<option>=X process.php top 3
```

Now I created a sh script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

php -d xdebug.<option>=X $1 $2 $3
```

But my issue is sometimes I have a different php script and different
parameters.

How can I make this work?

For example, so that I can call:

```
php process.php top 3 1 5
```

or

```
php process top 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: By the way it should be `-dxdebug.<option>=X` not `-d xdebug.<option>=X`

Comment: it works when I add the space ...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What arguments are you having in your bash script that can result in different behaviour? How much information does your script have, and have you tried using things as simple as conditionals?

Comment: @Pemapmodder A space (or, in fact, any number of spaces) between the option flag and argument for it is fine in >99% of programs, and the programs that don't accept it are broken and stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `$@`. This is a list of *all* arguments you passed to your shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

php -d xdebug.<option>=X "$@"
```

Now, if you call it as `./script.sh process.php top 3 1 5`, it will be expanded to:

```
php -d xdebug.<option>=X process.php top 3 1 5
```

Or if you call it as `./script.sh process.php top 10`, it will be expanded to:

```
php -d xdebug.<option>=X process.php top 10
```

If need more, you can perhaps play around with some `if` conditionals and `shift`. `shift` works like `array_shift()` in PHP in that if shifts an element off the beginning of `$@`. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

shortcut_args=""
if [ "$1" = "special_shortcut" ]; then
   shortcut_args="-d xdebug.<option>=X"
   shift
elif [ "$1" = "another_shortcut" ]; then
   shortcut_args="-d another.<option>=$2"
   shift; shift
fi

php $shortcut_args "$@"
```

This allows you to pass arbitrary arguments and still not type too much.

Comment: You must double-quote `$@` i.e. `"$@"` to prevent [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) otherwise it's just wrong and actually dangerous.

Comment: ...also check out [Bash FAQ 50 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) regarding `$shortcut_args`.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Thanks! I actually knew about `"$@"` but I somehow forgot :-/ I'll need to look at the second point later, since the proposed solution there seems awfully complex...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Cool. You've got my vote. BTW - you forgot to also double-quote the first `$@` in your first sentence :-) **tl;dr**: The second point talks about storing these arguments in an array instead of a variable. i.e. `$shortcut_args`.